# How do I receive traffic to the public IP of an additional ENI on EC2 Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2, linux-networking

I've added an additional network interface with elastic public and private ips.  In ubuntu I can see the interface getting a local IP from DHCP, but I cannot ssh to the additional public IP.

I'm pretty sure I've setup everything including security groups.  Am I missing something with the routing?  Or another way to test this additional public IP is attached?

Here's some console output:

```
ubuntu@ec2:~$ ip route show
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.86 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.40 

ubuntu@ec2:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:f7:07:ba:b8:d4  
          inet addr:10.0.0.86  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Interrupt:36 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:f7:07:90:7a:de  
          inet addr:10.0.0.40  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:544 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25133 (25.1 KB)  TX bytes:26283 (26.2 KB)
          Interrupt:38
```

Comment: maybe I need a second routing table for the second inet connection?

Comment: Any suggestions on documentation on this user254601?

Answer (score 1):

You will need add the rules in the Security Group via the console in AWS.

For SSH its something like this:

```
Create a new rule:
    ¬ SSH
         ¬ 0.0.0.0/0
              ¬ add rule
```

After that you should be able to ssh in via the elastic IP without restarting anything.

Comment: I have that rule already which allows me to ssh via the primary IP on eth0

Comment: You've set this rule in AWS? As the rules set here overule the rules set via the server.